# What happens when an accepted answer is deleted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022287/what-tag-do-i-use-to-start-my-html/5022306#5022306) a user accepted an answer that was later removed by being flagged.

Since the OP doesn't have 10k rep, they can't see the deleted answer, are they able to change the accepted answer or does the deleted answer stay accepted?

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't expect this to be a problem, since OPs can change accepted answers at will under normal conditions.

Comment: @Popular, I forgot about that. I was just curious if it would throw off things like the acceptance rate since it looks like the deleted answer is still considered the accepted answer. I was expecting it to be unmarked.

Comment: Wow, it actually *was* the correct answer.  Brilliant, if intentional, looks like it to me.  What a train wreck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an accepted answer is deleted (which can only happen by flagging or mod intervention), the acceptance vote is typically deleted along with it to allow a new answer to be selected.

Even if the acceptance mark is visible on the deleted answer (which I guess is the case for a flag deletion, given your >10k status and tone of question), remember that the question author doesn't have to manually unaccept an answer in order to accept a new one.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that you don't need to unaccept an answer in order to switch. The still green checkmark threw me. Thanks!