# Does multiple downvotes on accepted answer cause it to be deleted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, accepted-answer

On a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330079/regex-for-stock-quote/15330132), there was an accepted answer that the community seemed to disagree with. I went back to the answer later to see what had happened, and discovered that the accepted answer was completely removed. The last score I saw on the answer was -4.

I think I've seen other accepted answers with the score well into the negative territory. But it seems weird that the accepted answer did vanish. Do significantly downvoted accepted answers automatically remove themselves?

After some research, I found https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79582/215013, but it seems that only a flagging or a moderator can remove an accepted answer. But the accepted answer did answer the question, even if it was unpopular with the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No amount of downvotes will cause a post to be automatically deleted. But 20k users can vote to delete negatively voted answers. (And of course moderators can delete anything with no restrictions.)

In this case, the answerer deleted the answer himself - possibly as peer pressure from all the downvotes.

Note that is not possible for an accepted answer to be self-deleted.

So here's what happened:

1. Answer is posted.
2. OP recognizes that it works. Accepts it.
3. Other people downvote and comment explaining why the answer is bad.
4. OP unaccepts.
5. The answerer deletes his own answer.

Comment: Didn't think the OP would have unaccepted the answer, and the answer would have been deleted in such short order. But the chain of events makes sense. Thanks for the insight!